# Can the addition of an article change a noun from a thing to a place?

Tags: grammar, nouns

I'm an amateur trying to brush up on my grammar, and I've come across a confusing question.
Can the addition of an article change the type of a noun?
For example, if I used the term 'park', would this refer to a thing since I'm describing a broad class of things called 'parks'? With the addition of an article like 'the park', have I now changed the noun to a specific place rather than a thing? In general I'm having trouble distinguishing whether or not certain nouns are things or places. I'd greatly appreciate any help or insight. Thanks.